# smoothly make a div bigger in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can i make a div to blink two times and then it grows bigger on page load.

For example, the div will start with width: 50px; height:50px; and after blinking two times, it will smoothly grow to width: 250px; height:400px;

I've read about jQuery easing function, but i'm not familiar with jQuery i couldn't utilize the examples i found.

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: .animate will help you do both effects.

Comment: @azizpunjani could you show an example, as i have no former experience with jquery

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/Sw7kK/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get the job done in just a few lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/2vVpt/

```
$("#blinkandresize")
.fadeOut(300)
.fadeIn(300)
.fadeOut(300)
.fadeIn(300)
.animate({
    height: 400,
    width: 250
});​
```

Comment: How would you do this: - Keep the center of the element in place - while making the element wider. The intention is that the left and right side expand outwards at the same time.